# Replace .split() with .match() using regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm having difficulties with constructing some regular expressions using Javascript.

What I need:

I have a string like: `Woman|{Man|Boy}` or `{Girl|Woman}|Man` or `Woman|Man` etc.
I need to split this string by '|' separator, but I don't want it to be split inside curly brackets.

Examples of strings and desired results:

```
// Expample 1
string: 'Woman|{Man|Boy}'
result: [0] = 'Woman', [1] = '{Man|Boy}'

// Example 2
string '{Woman|Girl}|{Man|Boy}'
result: [0] = '{Woman|Girl}', [1] = '{Man|Boy}'
```

I can't change "|" symbol to another inside the brackets because the given strings are the result of a recursive function. For example, the original string could be

> 'Nature|Computers|{{Girls|Women}|{Boys|Men}}'

Comment: Regex isn't very good for this sort of search (where you basically have a stack of symmetrical "containers"). You get similar problems when you try to use Regex to parse HTML, for example...

Comment: @AssafLavie which method you recommend to use?

Comment: I would replace `|` by `,` and `{}` by `[]`, then add some quotes and use `JSON.parse("["+string+"]")` to convert that stuff into something that JS can easily handle. Works only if the original does not contain any of those characters, though.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
var reg=/\|(?![^{}]+})/g;
```

Example results:

```
var a = 'Woman|{Man|Boy}';
var b = '{Woman|Girl}|{Man|Boy}';

a.split(reg)
["Woman", "{Man|Boy}"]

b.split(reg)
["{Woman|Girl}", "{Man|Boy}"]
```

for your another question:

`"Now I have another, but a bit similar problem. I need to parse all containers from the string. Syntax of the each container is {sometrash}. The problem is that container can contain another containers, but I need to parse only "the most relative" container. mystring.match(/\{+.+?\}+/gi); which I use doesn't work correctly. Could you correct this regex, please? "`

you can use this regex:

```
var reg=/\{[^{}]+\}/g;
```

Example results:

```
    var a = 'Nature|Computers|{{Girls|Women}|{Boys|Men}}';

    a.match(reg)
    ["{Girls|Women}", "{Boys|Men}"]
```

Comment: @WoLpH thank you very much! Now I have another, but a bit similar problem. I need to parse all containers from the string. Syntax of the each container is `{sometrash}`. The problem is that container can contain another containers, but I need to parse only "the most relative" container. `mystring.match(/\{+.+?\}+/gi);` which I use doesn't work correctly. Could you correct this regex, please?

Comment: Starky: it's actually Tim. Tang's answer, I just added an example on how to use it :) Finding the "matching" brace is not really possible with regular expressions, you can find the closest or the furthes brace, but finding the matching brace requires tokenizing or something similar. Basically... a loop with a stack of braces opened/closed to know when one starts/stops again.

Comment: @WoLpH oh, yeah, a small mistake :) Thanks for your reply, I've already thought about that variant, but wanted to be sure it's not the bad way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
.match(/[^|]+|\{[^}]*\}/g)
```

to match those. However, if you have a nesting of arbitrary depth then you'll need to use a parser, [javascript] regex won't be capable of doing that.

Answer (score -2):

Test this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]*\|[a-zA-Z0-9]*)|{[a-zA-Z0-9]*\|[a-zA-Z0-9]*}
```